# Matplotlib rotate 3d object

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, rotation

I have two `Poly3DCollection` objects and I'm trying to rotate one of them: [image]

I tried to use the following code

```
t_start = ax.transData
t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(0.45, 0.45, 90)
t_end = t_start + t

cube.set_transform(t_end)
```

But the cube just disappear, I tried with a smaller angle 20° but the rotation is just weird, plus the cube seems to have a different position when I move the camera.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better library or should I code the rotation myself?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suspect this has something to do with using a 2D transformation on a 3D object.

Comment: I decided to code the rotation myself, it works nice